# Aligning list or table to center element

Tags: html, alignment, css-tables

I am trying to create a table or list width 5 elements.

```
<ul id="wrap">
  <li><hr></li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li><img/></li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li><hr></li>
</ul>
```

The ul width should be 100%.
The Image should always be the center of the page. (left:50% - width / 2).
The Text elements should "dock" to the image. (text-align: left // text-align: right).
So far so good, but now the problem,
the hr element widths should stretch across the rest of the ul width.
The left from 0 to the text elem, the right hr from right text to 100%.

I tried it with  a table and a li but couldn't manage to get it to work.

I'd be grateful for any help.